# How to do condition check if optional fields in a typescript union type?

Tags: typescript

I have several similar types like `{ value: number, type: 'number' }` and I was going to put them in union types such as:

```js
type UnionType1 = { value: number, type: 'number' } | { value: string, type: 'string' }
type Pass1 = UnionType1 extends { value: any, type: any } ? true : false
//   ^? type Pass1 = true
```

However, if one of the union types has an optinal field then the condition check would fail:

```js
type UnionType2 = { value: number, type: 'number' } | { value?: string, type: 'string' }
type Pass2 = UnionType2 extends { value: any, type: any } ? true : false
//   ^? type Pass2 = false
```

I want the `Pass2` also to be `true`, without changing the UnionType2, if but I don't know how.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/N926Jm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply make the `value` property optional too:

```js
type UnionType2 = { value: number, type: 'number' } | { value?: string, type: 'string' }
type Pass2 = UnionType2 extends { value?: any, type: any } ? true : false
```